# What free and efficient web/trafic filtering options are good for this situation?

Tags: network-monitoring, webfilter, traffic-management

**The Story (you can skip this if you like)**

So my girlfriend got a job as pedagog at a small boarding home (around 40 kids, age 10 to 18), 3 weeks ago. I went there once and surfed the web from a shared pc and noticed they were used for everything but educational purposes and full of ad-ware (from xxx dailers to smilies add-ons), p2p-clients (you name it) , and lots of illegal content which might get the institution in trouble.

My first Question was: *Who* is responsible for this PCs? The sad Answer: Nobody, some of the Kids helped set install them about 4 years ago.

My girlfriend told here boss, which asked how she found out about this, which led them to me, which brings me to this question.

just for background this is in Eastern Europe

**The Problem**

- Abuse of the network
- Illegal materials downloaded
- Network conjustions

**Hardware Architecture**

- 6 Shared PCs with Win 2k
- 1 Office PC  with Win XP - only one with printer
- 1 Huawei DSLModem/WLAN-Router
- 10 to 15 Notebooks connecting via WLAN
- 1 iPhone and 2 Nokia Phones (as listed on the DHCP client list)

**Budget**

0 , but there's an old PC , I think PIII 256mb Ram , currently with Windows ME (haven't seen that for a while); which no one is using.
Time: I've got about 4 to 5 hours each weekend I could volunteer there.

**Current Status**

- Cleaned and Locked down the shared PCs
- setted OpenDNS with category filtering as DNS in the router, they could be figuring out how to use GoogleDNS on their notebooks every moment now
- changed all password
- Enabled Guest account on the Office PC, and instructed the personnel to keep it locked as long as they are out of the office. Kids (should they need to print something) can use the Guest account

**The Final Words**

I already received a astonishing number of hate-mails throw that contact SysAdmin-Form on the OpenDNS BlockedDomain page.
I know this belongs more into a forum, but here are the most skilled people , and maybe someone is in a similar situation.
If you consider this should be removed from SF, please refer me to a good forum

---

What are my free and efficient filtering options?

---

Thank for reading.

**p.s. bonus question**
Kids come and ask my Girlfriend why they can't download torrents using there laptop, and they won't understand that they download illegal material, their argument "nobody around here ever got a fine". Now I want to make a poster explaining why their actions are a problem for the institution and why we are fighting them. Not that they would even read it, but at least I will try.

In the end I found [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/) to be a working solution, but the situation changed an I'm no longer responsible for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your P.S. kinda makes equivalent the notions "downloading a torrent" and "downloading illegal material / copyright infringement", which are still very different. Those kids claiming that "nobody around here ever got a fine" do have a point, as much as corporations from rich countries outsource jobs because of cheaper labor or register in certain places to minimize the taxes they pay. Yet those kids are wrong at the same time, because their extreme stance "we don't care" is as much wrong as yours "just totally block bittorrent or any other p2p".

Answer (score 1):

Total disclaimer here... I work for a company which makes software which does exactly this.

It isn't free, but there's no need for a server on your side (unless you really want one).  Just install the client on the machines, configure via a web interface and you are done.  It'll track or block what ever you are looking for, and you can be an fine toothed as you want with the blocking or allowing of websites.

You can also put up a customer file which tells people why they are blocked.

We do a free 30 day demo (I think it still says 7 days on the site because we just extended it yesterday) off [our site](http://www.awarenesstechnologies.com).

The sales pitch will now end.

Congrats to you for helping out and keeping her and her boss out of trouble, and for trying to teach the kids not to swipe software.